# $result_array only returning one row

Tags: php

The query below should return multiple ingredients, but it only returns one ingredient. What am I doing wrong?

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $result_array['id'] = $row['id'];
        $result_array['name'] = $row['product_name'];
        $result_array['phone'] = $row['categories_name'];
        $result_array['image'] = $row['url'];

        $sqlI = "SELECT * FROM `ingredients` inner join products_ingredients on ingredients.id=products_ingredients.idIngredient WHERE idProduct=".$row['id']."";
        $resultI = $conn->query($sqlI);

        if($resultI->num_rows > 0) {
            while($rowI = $resultI->fetch_array()) {
                $result_array['ingredients'] = $rowI['ingredient_name'];

            }
        } 
    array_push($products, $result_array);   
    }
}
```

And when I use echo it displays all the rows

```
 $sqlI = "SELECT * FROM `ingredients` inner join products_ingredients on ingredients.id=products_ingredients.idIngredient WHERE idProduct=".$row['id']." ORDER BY ingredient_name ASC";
    $resultI = $mysqli->query($sqlI);

    if($resultI->num_rows > 0) {
        while($rowI = $resultI->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $rowI['ingredient_name'].' <a href="removeProdIngred.php?id='.$rowI['id'].'">X</a><br />';
        }
    }
```

The output

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Supa de rosii (350 ml)
            [phone] => Supe
            [image] => https://restaurant.onlinebusiness.university/img/products/2/2.jpg
            [ingredients] => ceapa
        )
```

Comment: I presume your `idProduct` column is the primary key, therefore, a where clause on it will **only** ever return a single row

Comment: And the fact that you use; `$result_array['ingredients'] = $rowI['ingredient_name'];` in your loop, you never append to it, simply overwrite the `ingredients` key

Comment: what's the value of $resultI->num_rows?

Comment: @SamSwift웃 I've updated my answer with another piece of code, where it displays all the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `[]` after `$result_array['ingredients']` array, then it will store all ingredient_name name into array.

```
$result_array['ingredients'][] = $rowI['ingredient_name'];
```

Comment: This adds the previous values to the array

Comment: you need to create a new array and assign new array to $result_array['ingredients']  = $ingreadientsNameArray out of while loop.if($resultI->num_rows > 0) {
   $ingreadientsNameArray = array();
            while($rowI = $resultI->fetch_array()) {
    $ingreadientsNameArray[] = $rowI['ingredient_name'];
            }
   $result_array['ingredients'] = $ingreadientsNameArray;
        }

Comment: It only display one value, just like the first time